# Numerical Optimization over arrays of variable length

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider the following command line. We work in the n=2 dimensions, in the sense that I have an 'x' variable of dimension n=2, and n+1=3 variables y1, y2, y3 of dimension 2 each. I have hard coded as below and explicitly captured each scalar parameter in this setting.

```
(*All variables in the problem*)
Clear[t, x1, x2, x, y, y11, y12, y21, y22, y31, y32, innerOptProblem, 
  cRadContainer, cRad, cCenterContainer, Center];
```

```
innerOptProblem[y11_, y12_, y21_, y22_, y31_, y32_] :=  First[NMinimize[{t, 
     Norm[{x1, x2} - {y11, y12}, 2] <= t && 
     Norm[{x1, x2} - {y21, y22}, 2] <= t && 
     Norm[{x1, x2} - {y31, y32}, 2] <= t && 
     t >= 0}, {t, x1, x2}]] 

cRadContainer = NMaximize[{
   (* the objective *)   
   innerOptProblem[y11, y12, y21, y22, y31, y32], 

   (* a constraining set *)
   0 <= y11 <= 1 \[And] 0 <= y12 <= 1 && 
   Norm[{y11, y12}] >= 1/3 \[And] Norm[{y11 - 1, y12}] >= 2/3 && 

   0 <= y21 <= 1 \[And] 0 <= y22 <= 1 && 
   Norm[{y21, y22}] >= 1/3 \[And] Norm[{y21 - 1, y22}] >= 2/3 &&

   0 <= y31 <= 1 \[And] 0 <= y32 <= 1 && 
   Norm[{y31, y32}] >= 1/3 \[And] Norm[{y31 - 1, y32}] >= 2/3
    },
  (* the variables *)
  {y11, y12, y21, y22, y31, y32},
  (* the method *)
  Method -> "NelderMead"]
```

I wish to generalize this code for arbitrary n, and hence take away the need to reference each parameter in the problem explicitly. Given n, I essentially thus want to rewrite the entire code for an n-dimensional array x, and and (n)*(n+1) dimensional array y. Please help me do so, following being my failed attempt.

```
Clear[x, y, t]
n = 3;
const1[x_, y_, t_] := 
  Product[Boole[Norm[x - y[i], 2] <= t], {i, 1, n + 1}];
inneroptproblem[y_] := 
 First[NMinimize[{t, const1[x, y, t] == 1 && t >= 0}, {t, x}]];

const2[y_] := Product[Boole[Norm[y[[i]], 2] <= 1], {i, 1, n + 1}];
cradcontainer = 
  NMaximize[{inneroptproblem[y], const2[y] == 1}, {y}, 
   Method -> "NelderMead"];
```

To start with a small query, I wish to make something like the following work.

```
NMinimize[x[[1]]^2+ 2 x[[2]]^2, {x}]
```

Currently it does not work, since x is being perceived by the computer as a scalar.
How do I proceed?

Comment: For your 'small query', you need two things: 1) use `Indexed` instead of `Part`, and 2) use a vector domain for `x`. Putting it together: `NMinimize[Indexed[x, 1]^2 + 2 Indexed[x, 2]^2, x \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals]]`

Answer (score 4):

It may help if you elaborate more on the physical problem you're trying to solve. This is a generalization of your code to work for arbitrary dimension $n$, but I've added `MaxIterations` because it takes too long. With more info on what this is doing, I may be able to find a much faster solution.

I removed $t$ from the inner optimization since it seems unnecessary - you're basically minimizing the maximum distance of $x$ to all the $y$, and $t$ is the result, so it doesn't need to be a variable, nor do you need the $\ge0$ constraint.

The $Y$ is now an $n+1$ by $n$ matrix which makes it easier to specify as a domain argument to `NMaximize` instead of a list of component variables. The `outerConstraints` retain $Y$ as symbolic, so they need `Indexed`, but the `innerProblem` can take $Y$ as a numeric matrix and can use `Part`/`[[...]]`.

```
Remove["Global`*"];

NumMatrixQ[m_] := MatrixQ[m, NumericQ]
innerProblem[Y_?NumMatrixQ] :=
 With[{n = Length[Y[[1]]]},
  First@NMinimize[Max[EuclideanDistance[x, #] & /@ Y],
    x ∈ Vectors[n, Reals], MaxIterations -> 10]
  ]

outerConstraints[n_, Y_] :=
 And @@ Table[
   With[{y = Indexed[Y, i], offset = PadRight[{-1}, n]},
    (Norm[y] >= 1/3 )
     && (Norm[y + offset] >= 2/3)
     && (Min[y] >= 0)
     && (Max[y] <= 1)
    ], {i, n + 1}] 


outerProblem[n_] :=
 NMaximize[{
   innerProblem[Y],
   outerConstraints[n, Y]
   }, Y ∈ Matrices[{n + 1, n}, Reals],
  Method -> "NelderMead", MaxIterations -> 5]

cRadContainer = outerProblem[2]
```

Comment: For $n=2$ I got result `0.707107` which looks like $1/\sqrt{2}$. Does that meet your expectations?

Comment: The function `NumMatrixQ` is not necessary. You can use `innerProblem[Y_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ]&)] := ...` How long does your code take? I gave up on waiting.

Comment: @BobHanlon it takes 5-10 minutes or so. `NumMatrixQ` is there just because I dislike having complicated syntax crammed into the arguments.

Comment: @flinty for some reason, when I run your code, the following error shows up: `NMaximize::ivar: Y\[Element]Matrices[{3,2},\[DoubleStruckCapitalR],{}] is not a valid variable.`

Comment: @ShashankDeshpande what Mathematica version are you running? It works in 13.2.